# Why firestore giving: `Found conflicting getters for name error` even if there is no confliction?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried similar questions like [firestore-found-conflicting-getters-for-name-istext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308719/firestore-found-conflicting-getters-for-name-istext) but not helping, My actual error is
`Found conflicting getters for name getRatingDetail on class UserRatingSong`
my class structure is like this

```
interface UserRating<T : Rating> {
    val ratingDetail: T
    val userDetail: User
}  
data class UserRatingSong(override val ratingDetail: SongRating,override val userDetail: User) : UserRating<SongRating> {
    constructor() : this(SongRating(), User())
}  
interface Rating {
    var averageOfCategories: Float
}  

data class SongRating(override var averageOfCategories: Float,var singerRating: Float,var musicRating: Float,var lyricsRating: Float) : Rating {
    constructor() : this(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
}  
data class User(val userName: String, val userId: String, val profilePic: String) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "")
}
```

i am getting this error when trying adding new rating

```
fun addRating(userRating:UserRatingSong){
    firestore.collection("myCollection")
                .document("docId")
                .collection("userRatings")
                .document(userRating.userDetail.userId)
                .set(userRating)//error occurs here
}
```

as i have checked any of class memeber doesnot have similar names, i even also tried to change `ratingDetail` field name but also getting same error with changed field name

Comment: Do you mean that without `addRating` you get no error, but after adding it you do get one?

Comment: yes , when trying ro add rating i'm getting `Found conflicting getters for name getRatingDetail on class UserRatingSong`