# Parsing boolean from Firebase Database Snapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, proguard

I'm having issues pasing a Snapshot from the Firebase Realtime Database into a Data Class in Kotlin using ProGuard.

**Here's how the data looks in the Firebase console:**

[image: Firebase realtime database, screenshot of data]

**Here's how I've modeled that data class In my android app:**

```
data class PickupCode(
    val code: String,
    val boxId: String,
    val orderId: String,
    val suborderId: String,
    val drawers: List<Int>,
    val isDelivered: Boolean
) {
    constructor(): this("", "", "","", emptyList(), false)

    override fun toString(): String {
        return code
    }
}
```

**Here's how I build the database request:**

```
val reference = database.getReference("pickupCodes/$boxId/$code")

val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            println(snapshot)
            val pickupCode = snapshot.getValue<PickupCode>(PickupCode::class.java)
            pickupCode?.let {
                println("Code: ${it.code}, is delivered: ${it.isDelivered} to drawers: ${it.drawers.toString()}")
                if (!it.isDelivered) {
                    // No success
                } else {
                    // Success!
                }
            } ?: run {
                // No success
            }
        } else {
            // No success
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        // No success
    }
}
```

**This is what the `println(snapshot)` line prints:**

> DataSnapshot { key = 320625, value = {isDelivered=true, code=320625, drawers={0=2}, orderId=-LhdzXS4-gyT0ysNe-zi, suborderId=-LhdzYhT78y9b3iJcyrb, boxId=box_1} }

**And this is what the next print 3 lines lates prints:**

> Code: 320625, is delivered: false to drawers: [2]

Here I would expect `is delivered` to be `true`, but for some reason `true`-value of `isDelivered` from the snapshot, is ignored when parsing the snapshot into a `PickupCode`-class. The value `isDelivered` of the `PickupCode`, is equal to the empty constructor of the class.

**But WHY and HOW to fix?**

All the other values from the snapshot gets parsed corrently. I'm new to Android, but I have a hunch that ProGuard (whatever that is) has some of the blame here.. Here's how I've set it up:

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class PickupCode.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `isDelivered` in `println("Code: ${it.code}, is delivered: ${it.isDelivered} to drawers: ${it.drawers.toString()}")`? The same as in the `println(snapshot)`?

Comment: Nope :/ That's the one mentioned in the quote below. It's `false`..

Comment: But if you try print `it.isDelivered` outside the `pickupCode?.let` block, what is the value?

Comment: I found a solution, see below :)

Comment: Good to hear that :) I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49308903/5246885).

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this..
When inspecting the verbose logs I found this:

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for isDelivered found on class com.x.y.models.PickupCode

After playing a bit around, I found that for some weird reason, the setters for properties starting with `is` are ignored :S I tested with other property names as well and types.. fx. `val isBerp: Number` gets the same warning.

So after changing the property name from `isDelivered` to `delivered` in both the class and firebase, it works..

I wasn't able to find documentation for this behaviour, so if someone knows about it, it would appreciate a link..

Comment: Firestore removes `is` prefix from getters. See this link: https://www.e-learn.cn/en/node/1313471

Comment: facing same issue you save my 2 hours at least